# media page returnig to 404 in rtmedia

Tags: plugins, uploads, buddypress, media

I am using rtmedia plugin with buddypress plugin to uploading audio, video and image uploading. I am using latest version of both the plugins.
But when I browse to media page(i.e http://example.com/members/admin/media/) it returns to a 404 error, don't know what I am doing wrong.
Please Help me.

Comment: You can always check the support forum for the plugin as there are chances that the problem has already a solution there and you'll get a faster response. https://rtcamp.com/support/forum/rtmedia/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am from [rtMedia](http://rtcamp.com/rtmedia/) Team, please try to fix your Permalink to `http://example.com/%postname%/`
hope it will solve your problem